# 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll' available for Android and iOS?

Tags: .net, database, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, data-annotations

I got the the attached error message when tried to compile VelocityDB for android. As VelocityDB support said it really needs the data annotations.

Is the referred 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll' available for Android and iOS?

Thanks Jozsef

Error message:
"Error    1    Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'
   at Monodroid.Tuner.MonoDroidResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()"

Comment: Any updates from anyone?  Curious about this myself

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin.iOS 6.4.x (stable), like the 6.3.x betas, is based on Mono 3.0 and ships with `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`.

The same is true for the latest versions of Xamarin.Android.

Comment: How would you get it to work with monotouch and monodroid targets?  It seems to work when it's just a c# library project but once I change it to the ios or android targets I can't reference DataAnnotations.

Comment: The assembly (pre-compiled) binary is shipped with the beta. If you're using Xamarin.iOS 6.3+ simply double click on your project's **References**, select the **All** tab, click the checkbox before `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`, the click the **Ok** button.

Comment: I've checked with both the Alpha and the Beta and it doesn't show up in the All tab if I set my target to iOS or Android..

Comment: It might require a newer Xamarin Studio (from the beta channel) that will show the extraneous assemblies. OTOH you can manually refer it (for iOS) from `Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`. Xamarin for Android will have it under a similar path.

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin does not ship `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` at the moment (September 2012).

We'll soon rebase the products on Mono 2.12 which has much better support for .NET 4[.5] and that will make us able to ship more assemblies in the future (but I can't say **if** or **when** `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` will be available).

However Mono is an open source project. The source code for `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` is available on github so you can try, today, to build this assembly against the BCL that MonoTouch (or Mono for Android) ships. If you do then please share your finding with us!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to add System.ComponentModel from within VS 2012. I still do not have that dll available under Assemblies/Framework from with VS.

What I ended up doing was opening the project in Xamarin Studio on my MBP. I then was able to add the reference. I closed XS on the MBP and reopened the project in VS on my virtual machine and the reference was there. The solution compiled fine and ran in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not currently available.  Someone from Xamarin might be able to comment on their future inclusion in either product.

Answer (score 0):

Opened this bug on Xamarin that should be tracking this issue

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12053